# Got wrong value when using struct pointer as function parameter

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I met a very strange problem. 
I defined a struct and passed it as a const pointer into a function. The code is like bellow.

```
typedef struct a{
  char str1[256];
  ...
  int x;
}a_t;

int f(..., const a_t *a){...}

a_t a;
...
a.x = 1;
f(..., &a);
...
```

The problem is once it enters the f(), I will print out the variable a->x, which is always 0!??
But if I move the struct member x to the top of the struct (before other members), it will be 1, which is correct.

Are there any tricks or traps for using struct pointer as the parameter?

[EDIT1] The printf is called in the 1st line of function f()

Comment: Show what you put in the `f` function, you are likely overflowing the `str1` member.

Comment: Please try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), there is nothing special about pointers to structs.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot comment so I will suggest debugging option. Can you please add print of the struct element x address in the function and before. If it is the same someone is changing it, otherwise we are not looking at the same value.

```
typedef struct a{
  char str1[256];
  ...
  int x;
}a_t;

int f(..., const a_t *a)
{
    printf("X value %d, address %p", a->x, &(a->x));
    ...
}


a_t a;
...
a.x = 1;
printf("X value %d, address %p", a.x, &(a.x));
f(..., &a);
...
```

Also detail view of the function could help

Comment: Good suggestion on printing pointer address. Will post the result later.